Is it possible to reject an AWS IOT shadow update from a Lambda?
I have an AWS IOT thing. The thing writes to a shadow. The shadow has a rule that invokes a Lambda function. I want failure in that function to cause reject of the shadow update. Is this possible in AWS?
